# Alternative to onWindowFocusChanged in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using onWindowFocusChanged to detect a popup in my android application, and then kill the resulting popup. The problem with this approach is that the popup shows up for a really short period of time before the service related to the popup is actually killed by my code. Is there  any other "on" method or other approach that I can take to block the popup before it even shows up over my activity?

Comment: What kind of popup is it? Are you creating it somewhere before? Are you talking about a popup in a webview?

Comment: It is a TouchWiz popup. I want to disable the task manager, Calendar etc popups.

Comment: so it is a full screen activity you start when clicking on a widget or are you talking about a real popup? do you have some code you can show us already?

Comment: All I am doing is using the following code in my activity  public `void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   // Kill a service
        
 }`  Using this code I am able to kill a popup but I still see a flicker.

Comment: And with what code are you creating the popup? im still not sure what kind of popup you mean.

Comment: By popup I mean services started by TouchWiz from Samsung. Basically when you open the TaskManager widget from the bottom pannel it opens up on top of currently running activity and gains focus.

Comment: so lets try be exact here please, otherwise people wont be able to help you. What you mean is not a popup. Basically it starts the activity of the taskmanager if you open it. It is like opening an application. So what are you doing exactly now? It is still not clear. You are opening the taskmanager programmatically and then you want to close on focuschanged before you display the activity again?? Please provide some code. I really am in the dark about what you would like to do exactly.